# Convert television monitor for use on a boat

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I would like to install a large screen TV on a boat without having to use an inverter. This would involve modifying the power supply of the TV to take DC directly from the boat. The boat has two powerful 12V marine batteries. Large screen TV monitors, as I understand it, generally have the following power draws:

```
–24 V for backlighting power
12 V for the audio
5 V rail for system power
24 V rail for the LCD/LEDs
```

What would be a good approach for hooking this up to the boat's electrical supply? Has anybody here done this kind of conversion before?

Comment: *Large screen TV monitors, as I understand it, generally have the following power draws*. Your presumption is wrong.

Comment: Since you'd need DC-DC convertors to supply the various internal voltages ....why not simply use a DC-AC invertor with the onboard power supply. Your chances of getting all the supplies to cycle up in the right order is low ....it's simply too much work.

Comment: The only possibility for success is if  you can find a monitor (not a TV) that has a DC brick (similar to a laptop) power supply. Then you can read the voltage off of that supply and get a DC-DC converter to boost up from 12V to whatever the brick normally supplies.

Comment: Those voltages you mentions must occur in the proper sequence or damage will occur.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with comments above. It would be harder to interface 12V to an AC powered large monitor than to use a DC>AC inverter.

From my surveying various AC TV monitor PSU schematics, they 1st rectify AC line to DC with about 140% times the AC line voltage. Then step down to two or more DC voltages with a transformer with multiple primary and secondary windings for multiple feed-forward DC rectifiers and feedback for current surge control and voltage regulation.
[image]  ref : Samsung TV monitor PSU portion.

The 1st 3 stages of conversion above are "hot" AC>DC>AC>DC in the step down process with at least 2 DC output voltages "cold" due to galvanic isolation.

Xfrm Isolation is a necessary part for good performance with multiple video sources.

**Conclusion:** Don't use an AC large screen monitor and try to power it from the marine 12V batteries.  Use a large screen monitor designed to operate from DC instead.

Comment: All the regulation and surge control is for coping with an AC line source which is not relevant for a DC source. From the schematic it appears the "cold" side is what needs to be supplied in DC.

Comment: @TylerDurden: surge protection is also required for equipment operated on marine or automotive 12 V DC supplies.  But I do agree that the OP should look for a display that is intended to operate from a 12 V DC source if he doesn't want to use a 12VDC->120VAC inverter.

Comment: You might be able to supply 13V~14.2 to the high side from an LC filter and 5V to the low side (after power diode pair on cold side) and 0V return for each, but then any ground shift, load dump surges that interfere with video sources would need to be protected with surge and impedance control. Startup surges, and common mode noise issues will need to be addressed.